# update query not changed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I put gridview and I added hyperlink to take the user to other page and changed the status id based on a query but the problem that the update query is not worked even no error:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  style="margin:auto"  >
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="user enter">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/entry.aspx?request_id={0}",DataBinder.Eval (Container,"DataItem.request_id"))%>'  >
        enter </asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="visitor_mobile" HeaderText="visitor_mobile" SortExpression="visitor_mobile" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="request_id" HeaderText="request_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="request_id" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="request_date" HeaderText="request_date" SortExpression="request_date" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="visit_date" HeaderText="visit_date" SortExpression="visit_date" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="reason" HeaderText="reason" SortExpression="reason" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="status_name" HeaderText="status_name" SortExpression="status_name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and this is the code when user click enter it query to update the `status_id`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:visitormanagementConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="update dbo.requests set status_id=5
          where request_id= @request_id;" UpdateCommand="update dbo.requests set status_id=5 where request_id= @request_id">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="request_id" QueryStringField="request_id" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="request_id" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: your selectcommand and update command are same

Comment: check if @request_id actually matches any record first